# How to properly force HTTPS on specific pages using Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I would like to force my signup page to https, and allow all other pages to be browsed using https or http (e.g., http://www.example.com/signup should redirect to https://www.example.com/signup). I was able to force all pages to https, but cannot get only one page to redirect to https. The page just loads normally as http.

Here's the code I've been trying to use in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/signup(/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For what it's worth (in case there is a conflict I'm unaware of), I am also using the following code to force all pages to redirect to www and to drop the .php from the file names in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?/$1
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have your https rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(signup/?)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Remember that there is no starting slash `/` in RewriteRule.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to want to force https on the particular page (it stays as http).

Comment: @ken: Above rule will ONLY force https on `/signup/` URI but will not do so on eg: `/signup/login.php` URI. Is that the case with you as well that `/signup/` is being redirected to some other file? Your apache's access and error logs will also help me investigate further.

Comment: the specific URL to redirect to https is `https://www.example.com/signup` "Signup" is a php file, but I have used htaccess to remove the .php from the url. The only recent information in the error log is: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php53/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /opt/php53/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0."